# Set character limit on custom WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-fields

I'm searching for a solution for this for 2 days already, but none of the answers helped me out until now.

I have a WP_Query for a custom Wordpress loop and I want to show only posts with 100 characters or less (not words) in the the_content.

```
<?php $movies = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'showposts' => 4,
    )
);
 if($movies->have_posts()) : while($movies->have_posts()) : $movies->the_post(); ?>

       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <div id="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Is there any core solution that I can use as an array or I need to figure out another way to do this?

How can I get those results?

Thank you guys, you're amazing.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to search for posts that have 100 characters in the content, or do you want to get any posts but only show 100 characters (i.e. cut off the extra content)? It sounds like you want the first but it doesn't make much sense, so I assume you really want to truncate the length to 100 characters?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @FluffyKitten. Yes, I want the first one. Search for posts that have 100 characters or less and ignore the others that has 101 characters or more.

Comment: I'm not sure that's even possible through Wordpress. You would probably probably have to write a custom SQL query to query the database directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $movies = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'showposts' => 4,
    )
);
 if($movies->have_posts()) : while($movies->have_posts()) : $movies->the_post(); ?>

       <?php if(strlen(get_the_content()) <= 100): ?>

       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <div id="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: This won't actually work the way the OP wants... you are only getting 4 posts and then only displaying the ones with <=100 characters, so if all 4 of the posts have >100 characters it will actually display none.

Comment: You are wrong, also OP said its working the way he wants. You cant down vote because of that...

Comment: It just doesn't meet the requirements that were asked in the question, as I described. Test it and see. Maybe the OP hasn't actually had a query where they return posts with >100 chars yet, or maybe they didn't ask for what thy really wanted... either way, it doesn't answer *the question that was posted* which makes it incorrect, regardless of the OP's *intention* - this site is just as much for other users, and if anyone needs the functionality posted in the question, this answer will simply not work for them.